# Javascript wait for window to close before opening another

Tags: javascript

I need to open a series of popup windows, each window must be closed before the next one can be opened.

```js
function openWindows() {
    var urls = getListOfUrls();
    
    for (let url of urls) {
        openWindow(url);
        // Wait for window to close before continuing.
    }
}
```

The only way I found to make sure that a window is closed is to use a `setInterval` which, as I understand it, causes the function behave asynchronously.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: How the opened pop-ups are created, and specifically, how are they closed? Can you control the content of the pop-ups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential alternate suggestion**

Without more information, it sounds like what you're trying to accomplish can be completely automated using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and in-page scripting. If the URLs that you are visiting aren't all in the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), then this is the only method which will work (the solution below will not apply).

**Interpretation of question**

However, let's say that you need to manually perform some tasks on each page in order (one at a time) for whatever reason (maybe the pages you're retrieving often change their DOM in a way that keeps breaking your scripts), but you want to skip the rigor of serially opening the URLs in new tabs, so that you can just focus on the manual tasks.

**Solution**

JavaScript web APIs don't provide a way to check for the closure of a `window` (a script would no longer be running at that point), but the last event that you can respond to is the `unload` event, and using it would look something like this:

> References:
>
> - [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)
> - [`Window: unload event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)
> - [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)
> - [`Same-origin policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

```js
async function openEachWindowAfterThePreviousUnloads (urls) {
  for (const url of urls) {
    console.log(`Opening URL: "${url}"`);
    const target = '_blank';
    const initialTime = performance.now();
    const windowProxy = window.open(url, target);

    if (!windowProxy) {
      throw new Error(`Could not get window proxy for URL: "${url}"`);
    }

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      windowProxy.addEventListener('unload', ev => {
        const delta = performance.now() - initialTime;
        const thresholdMs = 1000;
        if (delta < thresholdMs) return;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}

const tags = [
  'javascript',
  'puppeteer',
];

const urls = tags.map(tag => `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/${tag}`);

openEachWindowAfterThePreviousUnloads(urls);
```

[Code in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI3QBwKYQCiwUAFgOqoQAm6A7gIJzJ4BOAKqXgAqt4BuGBCACqEADbpg1EDAAUCVuJAAuGCGSsqAcwDaAXQCUa3ugC2qEHgA8-dKmoA+GAG8AUDHjpW8qJg0wiuLYcIFKIIauHp4wfhAg6OJ4AHSS2nIABgDy+BA6MCIASgAyagBEACQuQQC+ZRmGANzRnnEByMCs2njIMAC8MADkAPoARuLAEADWg80xsf69VKhowOLsqGZ4-TD4rHDeZpNQKRD0ck0tC-G9dFS0dKYAHmA7dzT0ybgECkoANDAOl0epcrqhQnIAITvB7PMCRdzzTzIUisegwCB4OgwQisNGsTIAYXQCHE1Ax6F63Vu93RODRLy8PiKpRglWqSjqDTmMRqbiuwDowBWGKxMFMFistnsTjkfAS4n42z6zkRSJh9DhyWk1EISogyGKlhYmIJgyQkmkgwBAn6qqu8zavWoeHEHR2ewOrCO0FO50iAFoYMtVutNngeUjru1UXgQKREtQALKyAYARgADFnI0jwfIXW7gDBrIDY-HEynInxkIoIDn5vLEkqLvWYDVLvN2zy+Xy3E7AcBtKmYLpooMAFbAfigKBaHDIa1jnAIHD4FhsRf6Zp9xZhZQ7DpD5JHHByQ92mAZUjIZA4VQAenvGhIU3QSv2kjoyT8ZnvAEcEDjNB-HvQ9umoe8qkPGpuX5b4iBIChaUYZg2E4Hg+EEElRAkKQZF+ZRLiAA)

**Caveats:**

The script will fail if any of the following is not true:

- Every URL is in the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) as that of the invoking window
- If your browser blocks pop-ups, the page where you run the script is allowed to create pop-ups. Example error:

  [image: pop-up blocked]

---

You can try the code above in your browser JS console on this page, and (as long as `https://stackoverflow.com` is allowed to create popups) it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately the solution you suggested has the same problem I got stuck on, the pages all open at once. I guess I'll have to find a completely different approach to get around this problem.

Comment: @Ughy23 You're right — that was due to multiple `unload` events being fired. I updated my answer to include a conditional check to prevent resolving the promises if they occur within a time threshold. Does that work for you now?